# Is it possible to calculate a p-value from a modified test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, p-value, goodness-of-fit

I was asked to fit a distribution to some data and calculate the goodness-of-fit and a corresponding p-value. I've been using Pearsons chi-squared test (chi2gof in matlab) to do this but my advisor told me to used a separate equation to calculate the test statistic. Instead of Pearson's equation, I've been asked to use $\chi^2=\frac{1}{n−m}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(Oi−Ei)^2}{σ_i}$, where $m$ are the degrees of freedom and $σ$ is the standard error of each histogram bin. I'm not familiar enough with statistics to know if we can just modify a test like that and get meaningful results. I imaging I would have to make a new test but I don't know how I'd go about doing that. I'd appreciate hearing some others thoughts on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach to estimate a p-value is to simulate from the null distribution and determine how often the test statistic is as extreme as (or more extreme than) the result from your sample.

Take the distribution that you are checking for goodness-of-fit, simulate data, calculate your (modified) test statistic, repeat.